# My bibliography isn't appearing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, apa-style, preamble

I am using biber for my citations for the first time, and although I followed all turtorials the command `\printbibliography` simply doesn't do anything. Who knows how to fix the problem? Please find the preamble below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel} % english or dutch
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa} % map dutch to dutch-apa
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa} % map english to english-apa
\addbibresource{ThesisBib.bib}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Tex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{
  nodate = {z\adddot j. \adddot}
}
\addbibresource{ThesisBib.bib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\lstset{language=Tex}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}             %VERWIJDEREN VOOR UITVOER
%\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\selectlanguage{dutch}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[small,bf,hang]{caption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{en}}  %Slight twist to accomodating for Dutch 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%Latex logo
\usepackage{doc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
    {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt}

\geometry{dvips,a4paper,margin=1.5in}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{.png}{.pdf}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\newcommand{\qi}{(\textit{i})\xspace}
\newcommand{\qii}{(\textit{ii})\xspace}
\newcommand{\qiii}{(\textit{iii})\xspace}
\newcommand{\qiv}{(\textit{iv})\xspace}
\newcommand{\vbl}[1]{(\textit{#1})\xspace}
\newcommand{\vblp}[1]{(\textit{#1})\xspace}
\newcommand{\vblt}[1]{\textit{#1}\xspace}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mbox{var}(#1)\xspace}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\mbox{Var}(#1)\xspace}
\newcommand{\cov}[1]{\mbox{cov}(#1)\xspace}
\newcommand{\Cov}[1]{\mbox{Cov}(#1)\xspace}
\newcommand{\coo}{CO\textsubscript{2}}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Bijlagen}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Bijlagen}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\huge\thechapter}{1em}{\Huge}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \lhead{\textit{Bachelorscriptie Emotional Labor}}
    \cfoot{Pagina \thepage~van \pageref{LastPage}}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}
```

Comment: Unrelated but do you need all of the things in this preamble? You have some `natbib` commands that shouldn't be there if you're using `biblatex`, for example. e.g. `\bibpunct` and the redefinition of `\harvardand`.  You're loading `lmodern` and `mathpazo`, and `palatino`. You're loading some packages multiple times. It might be a good idea to figure out what you're actually using and why and trim all the stuff you don't need.

Comment: It's also likely that the `natbib` commands I mentioned will simply cause compilation errors since you're not loading `natbib` (and you shouldn't).